# Start Rails server on Vagrant using .bat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, batch-file, vagrant

I'm using Vagrant on Windows, so I need many command prompts in order to do some basic stuff - one for Git, other for `rails server`, third for tests etc.

I want to make .bat files for starting Rails server and running tests.

So, I've created .bat file with this content (most lines are copied from git-cmd.bat):

```
@rem Do not use "echo off" to not affect any child calls.
@setlocal

@rem Get the abolute path to the current directory, which is assumed to be the
@rem Git installation root.
@for /F "delims=" %%I in ("%~dp0") do @set git_install_root=%%~fI
@set PATH=%git_install_root%\bin;%git_install_root%\mingw\bin;%git_install_root%\cmd;%PATH%

@if not exist "%HOME%" @set HOME=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%
@if not exist "%HOME%" @set HOME=%USERPROFILE%

@set PLINK_PROTOCOL=ssh

D:
@cd D:\Documents\GitHub\blog
@start %COMSPEC%

vagrant ssh -c "cd /vagrant && rails s"
```

It starts the server and stops it immediately. After that it closes the window. Also, it's opening extra command prompt window. Why is that?

How can I make it start the server and stay open? I've tried with `pause`, `/wait` and `cmd /k file.bat`, without success.

Ideally, I would have 4/5 .bat files: vagrant_up.bat, vagrant_halt.bat, rails_server.bat (or rails_start.bat and rails_stop.bat) and rake_test.bat. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is opening the extra window

```
@start %COMSPEC%
```

Not knowing vagrant, but I suspect this line should be like this, or ditch the %comspec% part altogether if Vagrant is an exe.

```
@start "" %COMSPEC% vagrant ssh -c "cd /vagrant && rails s"
```

Or maybe this was meant:

```
@start "" %COMSPEC% -c "cd /vagrant && rails s"
@vagrant ssh
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. I've just removed %COMSPEC% part and it works perfectly. Welcome to StackOverflow :)